# How can I add a new method to a linked list instance?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I have declared a `class` called `ResultClass` and I have made a `linkedList` from that

```
private LinkedList<ResultClass> listOfResults;
```

Now I want to add a new method called `getSample(Double d)` that I wish to use that like `listOfResults.getSample(0.5)`. How can I declare a method like that in Java?

Comment: Simple: you can not.

Comment: Build your own `LinkedList` class.

Comment: Either you build your own class, or you build a class that has a method that accepts a list as input and returns the result you need (that is, the list doesn't have a method, but it is used in the method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to create a new class for this. E.g.:

```
public class SamplingLinkedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
   public List<T> getSample(double d) {
       return // something;
   }
}
```

Comment: in the the original `LinkedList` sample I have a list that have several objects in it. I wanted to do some operation on them with aforementioned method  `getSample` and I want to return some part of the original linked list. in your solution for this problem, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are talking about that [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) that comes as java.util - the answer: you can't do that. In contrast to other programming language, Java does not allow you to **add** methods to existing classes (unless you own the source code and can **change** that class implementation).

The one thing you can do: create your own implementation of the List interface (and use that LinkedList to implement that) and add those methods you are looking for. The easiest way to get there would be by extending java.util.LinkedList; but in case you *favor composition over inhertiance* you might choose to fully implement that List interface yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add a method to a *class* is to extend the class:

```
class MyResultList extends LinkedList<ResultClass>
```

And add the method there.

But this requires you to create instances of that class: you can't "retrofit" the method to existing instances.

An easier alternative is to declare a method which takes the linked list as a parameter:

```
static ResultClass getSample(LinkedList<ResultClass> results, double valye)
```

There's no need for this to be in that linked list's class.

There may not even be a need to require the use of `LinkedList` as the parameter: maybe the method's logic would still work with `List`, `Collection` or `Iterable` instead. This would make the method much more generally applicable. You can't do that with the inheritance-based approach.

Comment: Hint: why take a LinkedList for the static method; List would do.

Comment: @GhostCat not if `getSample`  uses `LinkedList`-specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

- Define it as the `getSample` method in `ResultClass`.
- Extend LinkedList (possible by just wrapping a real one, in which case your doing option 1)
- Use `static` method that takes the linked list as additional parameter, it can be defined anywhere.